# Convert enum to JsonValue based on enum index

Tags: flutter, dart

In order to deserialise int from backend to my custom enum in dart I need to use this code which looks weird:

```dart
enum ActionStatus {
  @JsonValue(0)
  none,
  @JsonValue(1)
  done,
  @JsonValue(2)
  failed,
  @JsonValue(3)
  skipped,
}
```

Can it somehow be done automatically based on an enum index ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, although you would need to change the type of data which you store in the backend for the enumIndex.

```dart
enum ActionStatus {
  @JsonValue(0)
  none,
  @JsonValue(1)
  done,
  @JsonValue(2)
  failed,
  @JsonValue(3)
  skipped; // Semi-colon here lets us add methods to an Enum.

  int toJson() {
    return index; // index is a built-in getter for the index of an Enum's value;
  }

  factory ActionStatus.fromJson(int index) {
    return values[index]; // values is list of all values of the Enum.
  }
}
```

You can save your enum in the backend as an int and then you can get your `int` denoting the index from the backend, Pass the index to the `ActionStatus.fromJson` constructor to get it back as an `ActionStatus`.

**Note: This way of declaring this requires you to have `Flutter version > 3.0.0` and `dart version > 2.17.0`**

Comment: Looks like it works without these methods. I'd like to get rid of that @JsonValue(n) lines

Comment: Are you using `json_annotation` package Mr Adam? Because `@JsonValue(n)` is not defined by flutter itself. Also, it is not possible to convert or serialize the `enum` without the annotations.